# Flask-WTForm not submitting value

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

so after a user complained an error message, I discovered that my bank account field was not validating a length validator (WTForm). I disabled the length validator and implemented it myself. The error I therefore received was `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'length'` and if I tried, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`. Clearly something was wrong. I have countless other forms all that behave perfectly, except this one. I cannot FOR THE LIFE of me, understand why this is. Everything seems to be setup properly. Here is my code:

**Form**

```
class onboard_form(FlaskForm):
    full_name = StringField('Full Name (as it appears on your bank account)', validators=[
        InputRequired(message='Please enter a valid name.')])
    sort_codeone = StringField('Sort Code', validators=[(InputRequired(
        message='Please enter a valid sort code.'))])
    sort_codetwo = StringField('...', validators=[
        InputRequired(message="Please enter a valid sort code.")])
    sort_codethree = StringField('...', validators=[
        InputRequired(message='Please enter a valid sort code.')])
    account_number = StringField('Account Number', validators=[
        InputRequired(message='Please enter a valid account number.')])
    comfirm_account_number = StringField('Confirm Account Number', validators=[
        InputRequired(message='Please enter a valid account number.')])
    terms = BooleanField("I understand that I am responsible for providing a valid bank account.", validators=[
                         InputRequired(message='Please accept the terms and conditions.')])

    def validate(self, extra_validators=None):
        if super().validate(extra_validators):
            # Check is sort code is valid
            if not ((self.sort_codeone.data).isdigit() and (self.sort_codetwo.data).isdigit() and (self.sort_codethree.data).isdigit()):
                self.sort_codeone.errors.append(
                    'Please enter a valid sort code.')
                return False
            if (((self.sort_codeone.data).length() != 2) or ((self.sort_codetwo.data).length() != 2) or ((self.sort_codethree.data).length() != 2)):
                self.sort_codeone.errors.append(
                    'Please enter a valid sort code.')

                return False
            # Check account number is valid
            if ((self.account_number.data).length != 8):
                self.account_number.errors.append(
                    'Please enter a valid account number.')

                return False
            if ((self.account_number.data) != (self.comfirm_account_number).data):
                self.comfirm_account_number.errors.append(
                    "Please enter the same value as above.")
            else:
                return True
```

**Page that calls it**

```
@app.route('/onboard', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def onboard():
    name = Users.get_by_id(session["user_id"]).first_name + " " +  Users.get_by_id(session["user_id"]).last_name
    form = onboard_form()
    form.full_name.default = name
    form.process()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(form.sort_codeone)
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            sort_code = form.sort_code_1.data + "-" + \
                form.sort_code_2.data + "-" + form.sort_code_3.data
            Users.update(bank_full_name=form.full_name.data, bank_sort_code=sort_code,
                         bank_account_number=form.account_number.data).where(Users.id == session["user_id"]).execute()
            return redirect('/newevent')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return render_template('bank-details.html', form=form)
    else:
        return render_template('bank-details.html', form=form)
```

**Html Template**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
Enter Bank Details
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<h3 class="py-5 text-4xl text-center">Onboard</h3>
<p class="text-center">To start adding events, please enter your bank details so that people can buy tickets from you!
</p>

<form id="form" action="/onboard" method="post" class="px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4  rounded">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="text-center  mb-4">
        {{ form.full_name.label(class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900") }}
        {{ form.full_name(class_="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5", placeholder="John Smith") }}
        <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500">{{ form.full_name.errors[0] }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="mb-4 px-2">
            {{ form.sort_codeone.label(class_="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900") }}
            {{ form.sort_codeone(class_="w-full bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded appearance-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5", placeholder="67") }}
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4 px-2">
            <p class="text-xl pt-8">-</p>
        </div>


        <div class="mb-4 px-2">
            {{ form.sort_codetwo.label(class_="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900") }}
            {{ form.sort_codetwo(class_="w-full bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded appearance-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5", placeholder="34") }}
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4 px-2">
            <p class="text-xl pt-8">-</p>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-4 px-2">
            {{ form.sort_codethree.label(class_="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900") }}
            {{ form.sort_codethree(class_="w-full bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded appearance-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5", placeholder="75") }}
        </div>

    </div>
    <p class="text-center mb-4 text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500">{{ form.sort_codeone.errors[0] }}</p>
    <div class="text-center mb-4 px-2">
        {{ form.account_number.label(class_="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900") }}
        {{ form.account_number(class_="w-full bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded appearance-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5", placeholder="12345678") }}
        <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500">{{ form.account_number.errors[0] }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center mb-4 px-2">
        {{ form.comfirm_account_number.label(class_="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900") }}
        {{ form.comfirm_account_number(class_="w-full bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded appearance-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2.5", placeholder="12345678") }}
        <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500">{{ form.comfirm_account_number.errors[0] }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="py-3 flex items-center mb-4">
        {{ form.terms(class_="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 rounded border-gray-300 focus:ring-sky-500") }}
        {{ form.terms.label(class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900") }}
        <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500">{{ form.terms.errors[0] }}</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="mb-6 text-center">
        <button
            class="text-white bg-sky-700 hover:bg-sky-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-sky-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center"
            type="submit">
            Confirm
        </button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Again, I have countless other forms and I don't understand what's wrong here!

Comment: Python strings don't have a `length()` method, did you mean to use the `len` function that takes a string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had an extra line:
`form.process()`
Why I honestly don't know how it got there but it wiped the form. Very strange